# Which tags should we use for questions about Carthage and the Phoenicians?

Tags: discussion, tags

There have been a few questions about Carthage lately, for example:

- [Do we consider Carthage as belonging to a different civilization from the Phoenician one?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/7327/do-we-consider-carthage-as-belonging-to-a-different-civilization-from-the-phoeni)
- [What is the state of the art historical analysis of claims that Carthaginians discovered America?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/7326/what-is-the-state-of-the-art-historical-analysis-of-claims-that-carthaginians-di)

Should we be using the [carthage](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/carthage) tag or the [phoenicians](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phoenicians) tag for such questions, or both? Should we create a [punic](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punic) tag? And should we use [phoenicians](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phoenicians) or [phoenicia](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phoenicia) for questions about Phoenicians?

I'm asking because I'm interested in filling in the descriptions of the tags.